# Select the values in pop dataframe which its index in index_par dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, genetic-algorithm

I'm buliding genetic algorithm for feature selection. And I'm having some difficulties.

I have **pop** dataframe (population), consist of 20 individus and 9 features:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   
0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1
1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0
2   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1
3   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1
4   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0
5   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
6   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
7   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1
8   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1
9   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
10  0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1
11  1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0
12  0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0
13  0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0
14  1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
15  1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1
16  1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0
17  1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1
18  1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
19  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
```

And I have **index_par** dataframe, consist of index number:

```
    0
0   0
1   1
2   4
3   5
4   8
5   10
6   11
7   13
8   14
9   19
```

The **index_par** dataframe is the indexes of selected parent for crossover.

How can I select the values in **pop** dataframe which its index in **index_par** dataframe? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) by column `0` of `index_par`:

```
index_par = pd.DataFrame({0:[0,1,4,5,8,10,11,13,14,19]})

df3 = pop.loc[index_par[0]]
print (df3)
    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
0   0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  1
1   0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0
4   1  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
5   1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1
8   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  1
10  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1
11  1  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
13  0  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
14  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  1  0
19  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
```